# Conditional if clause

Tags: grammar, conditionals, subordinate-clauses

Can we use the first conditional to show general truth?
e.g : If you don't put some cherries on your cake, it will look pale and dull.
Is the word WILL here acceptable?

Comment: There is nothing odd about that.

Comment: If you don't it will - if you didn't it would. The second is more hypothetical.

Comment: But, many references I've read say that General Truth should be expressed by Zero Conditional, while the first conditional on the other hand is for possible result.

Comment: So, please help me with it,

Comment: Which one is correct? If you ..., it will look pale and dull. Or: If you ..., it looks pale and dull.

Comment: The first is correct, the second is not as much so because you are mixing future tense with present tense. If the speaker is particularly enthusiastic about cherries on cakes, then they describe it as a general truth to emphasize their point of view. I wouldn't say it's breaking the rules.